# Skip a number of iterations during foreach

Tags: php

I would like to skip a number of iterations of a foreach loop.

I have this code;

```
    $myarray = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h");
    $skip = 5;
    foreach($myarray as $key => $letter){
        if($key < $skip){
            $key = $skip;
        }
        echo $letter;
    }
```

This code doesn't do the trick. But with it I can sort of explain what I want. I what to actually move the pointer of the next iteration. It thought that by modifying the value of the key to the one i want would be enough. I understand that a possible solution would be this.

```
    $myarray = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h");
    $skip = 5;
    foreach($myarray as $key => $letter){
        if($key < $skip){
            continue;
        }
        echo $letter;
    }
```

But that kinda still does the iteration step. I would like to completely jump over the iteration.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do it with a foreach, you'd have to use a regular for loop, which isn't what you wanted I'm guessing by your title...

Comment: ITs printing f-g-h , it means it is skipping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a for loop instead

EDIT:

```
for($i = $skip; $skip > 0, $i < count($myarray); $i++) {
   // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Huh? That gives -1. `for ($i = 5; $i < count($myarray); $i++) { [...] }`

Answer (score 2):

See: [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/function.array-slice.php)

```
$myarray = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h");
foreach(array_slice($myarray, 5) as $key => $letter){
    echo $letter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how `foreach` loops (and iteration in general) work.

You can either do the `continue` version (which works fine; if it's the first thing in the loop body, it's essentially the same), or you can construct a different array to iterate over that doesn't include the first elements, or you can use a regular `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (array_slice($myarray, 5) as $key => $letter) {
[...]
}
```

Comment: Huh? 'fgh' seems to be exactly the respected result, because this is the same result as of the accepted solution by the poster!?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 $myarray = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h");
    $skip = 5;
    $index = 0 ;
    foreach($myarray as $key => $letter){
        if( ($index % $skip) == 0 ){
           echo $letter;
        }       
        $index++;

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myarray = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h");

foreach (new LimitIterator (new ArrayIterator ($myarray), 5) as $letter)
{
        echo $letter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `$array->next()` for `$skip` times. There are cases when you cannot easily use a regular `for` loop: for example when iterating a `DatePeriod` object.